# How to override catalog price render file

Tags: magento-2.1, price, catalog, product-prices

I want to make a modification with the price shown in catalog view page so i have to modify `_toHtml()` in `module-catalog\pricing\render.php` I am not sure what is the best way to do that.

for example, for listing page, i used a plugin for the `aftergetProductPrice()` function of `catalog\Product\ListProduct.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to rewrite the price of listing page, it is fine in this case.
But in most cases, we want to rewrite all the price in all page.

In those cases, you should rewrite method **format** of \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency class.

P/s: you can either using **prefences** or **plugin**

**Edited**: 
If you want to also modify the price in product view page, checkout page, cart page (these pages using knockoutjs to render the price format).

Rewrite the **formatPrice**() method in Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils

For me, i added the configuration in admin dashboard. And then i add these line of code to the formatPrice() method:

```
 if (typeof window.precision !== 'undefined') {
            precision = window.precision;
        }
```

This is the eddited method:

```
 /**
 * Formatter for price amount
 * @param  {Number}  amount
 * @param  {Object}  format
 * @param  {Boolean} isShowSign
 * @return {String}  Formatted value
 */
function formatPrice(amount, format, isShowSign) {
    format = _.extend(globalPriceFormat, format);

    // copied from price-option.js | Could be refactored with varien/js.js

    var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
        integerRequired = isNaN(format.integerRequired = Math.abs(format.integerRequired)) ? 1 : format.integerRequired,
        decimalSymbol = format.decimalSymbol === undefined ? ',' : format.decimalSymbol,
        groupSymbol = format.groupSymbol === undefined ? '.' : format.groupSymbol,
        groupLength = format.groupLength === undefined ? 3 : format.groupLength,
        pattern = format.pattern || '%s',
        s = '',
        i, pad,
        j, re, r, am;

    if (typeof window.precision !== 'undefined') {
        precision = window.precision;
    }


    if (isShowSign === undefined || isShowSign === true) {
        s = amount < 0 ? '-' : (isShowSign ? '+' : '');
    } else if (isShowSign === false) {
        s = '';
    }
    pattern = pattern.indexOf('{sign}') < 0 ? s + pattern : pattern.replace('{sign}', s);

    // we're avoiding the usage of to fixed, and using round instead with the e representation to address
    // numbers like 1.005 = 1.01. Using ToFixed to only provide trailig zeroes in case we have a whole number
    i = parseInt(amount = Number(Math.round(Math.abs(+amount || 0) + 'e+' + precision) + ('e-' + precision)) , 10) + '';
    pad = (i.length < integerRequired) ? (integerRequired - i.length) : 0;

    i = stringPad('0', pad) + i;

    j = i.length > groupLength ? i.length % groupLength : 0;
    re = new RegExp('(\\d{' + groupLength + '})(?=\\d)', 'g');

    // replace(/-/, 0) is only for fixing Safari bug which appears
    // when Math.abs(0).toFixed() executed on '0' number.
    // Result is '0.-0' :(


    am = Number(Math.round(Math.abs(amount - i) + 'e+' + precision) + ('e-' + precision));
    r = (j ? i.substr(0, j) + groupSymbol : '') +
        i.substr(j).replace(re, '$1' + groupSymbol) +
        (precision ? decimalSymbol + am.toFixed(2).replace(/-/, 0).slice(2) : '');

    return pattern.replace('%s', r).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
}
```

Note: the window.precision is the global variable that i assigned to when loading the page.

Comment: The suggestion is not working on product view page.

Comment: Yeah. some places magento use knockoutjs to render the price format (product detail page, checkout page).
Do you want to fix that, too ?

Comment: Basically, i want to have a solution for product view page, as i am not getting the way from where o modify it. I am successfully able to do it on list and front page blocks. If u can just guide me with product view page that will be helpful. As currently i can see that it is coming from module-catalog\pricing\render.php but i am not sure how to override this and what will be the best way to modify that price.

Comment: I have just updated my answer, please have a look at that

Comment: I tried to return some random value from format price function but it did not make any change.

Comment: Have you cleaned all cache ? 
Try console.log() to see whether your value is assigned

Comment: Yes  i did, well I just want to hide the price.  I just checked that i am able to modify the price from \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency convertAndRound() function but this just modifies the price not hide.

Comment: Well, then return '' (emty string) in method format of \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency class. That is done.

Comment: public function afterFormat(
          \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency $subject,
          $result
      )
      {
          return "";
      }

Comment: got that let me try

Comment: This is a plugin method for the \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency class.

I have just tested it. and it works well. 
This is my result: http://prntscr.com/fz4yvz

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: i am getting it fine on list or other page but no on view page(product view page)

Comment: If you just want to hide the price in product view page, rewrite the reloadPrice() method in module Magento_Catalog/js/price-box. I have tested on my local machine and it worked very well. http://prntscr.com/fz8k3s http://prntscr.com/fz8l3u

Comment: Try it and let me know whether it works or not

Comment: I modified the line $('[data-price-type="' + priceCode + '"]', this.element).html('testy');
            }, this); but no luck. line no 149 in price-box.js

Comment: Delete all the lines in function reloadPrice() from line 138 to line 151 in pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\Magento_Catalog\js\price-box.js work for me.

Comment: Note: you also have to rewrite the format method in  \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency

Comment: I have currently rewrite module-catalog\pricing\render.php _toHtml itself not sure if that is best way or not. But thanks for your help